# Tensorflow subtract strange result

Tags: tensorflow

Can someone explain the weird results I get from this trivial code? Am I doing sth wrong? Why input params a_C and a_G change? What has the difference result to do with the passed values?

```
#-----------------------------

def dummy_function(a_C, a_G):

  diff = tf.subtract(a_C, a_G)    
  sqr = tf.square(diff)

  return a_C, a_G, diff, sqr

#-----------------------------

tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.Session() as test:

  tf.set_random_seed(1)

  a_C = tf.random_normal([1], mean=1, stddev=4)    
  a_G = tf.random_normal([1], mean=1, stddev=4)    
  a_C_returned, a_G_returned, diff, sqr = dummy_function(a_C, a_G)

  print("a_C = " + str(a_C.eval()))    
  print("a_G = " + str(a_G.eval()))    
  print("a_C_returned = " + str(a_C_returned.eval()))    
  print("a_G_returned = " + str(a_G_returned.eval()))    
  print("diff = " + str(diff.eval()))    
  print("sqr = " + str(sqr.eval()))

#-----------------------------    
# results

a_C = [-1.68344498]    
a_G = [-0.39043474]    
a_C_returned = [ 4.70364952]
a_G_returned = [ 0.84769011]
diff = [-9.30598831]
sqr = [ 25.68828583]
```

Thank's in advance for any help,
Best regards,
Kasia

Answer (score 2):

Your a_C is not the resulting tensor of `tf.random_normal`!. It is the operation to get random numbers in each `eval`. That's the best demonstration for **never** using `.eval()`.

Instead, you need to evaluate these tensors within *one* run like

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def dummy_function(a_C, a_G):

  diff = tf.subtract(a_C, a_G)
  sqr = tf.square(diff)

  return a_C, a_G, diff, sqr

with tf.Session() as sess:

  tf.set_random_seed(1)

  a_C = tf.random_normal([1], mean=1, stddev=4)
  a_G = tf.random_normal([1], mean=1, stddev=4)
  a_C_returned, a_G_returned, diff, sqr = dummy_function(a_C, a_G)

  a_C_, a_G_, a_C_returned_, a_G_returned_, diff_, sqr_ = sess.run([a_C, a_G, a_C_returned, a_G_returned, diff, sqr])

  print("a_C = " + str(a_C_))
  print("a_G = " + str(a_G_))
  print("a_C_returned = " + str(a_C_returned_))
  print("a_G_returned = " + str(a_G_returned_))
  print("diff = " + str(diff_))
  print("sqr = " + str(sqr_))
```

This guarantees that all returned results are based on the *same* entry nodes (ie. `a_C, a_g`)

Comment: Thank you very very much :)