# confusion in different ways to open a session and executing the graph in tensorflow

Tags: session, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to learn deep learning with tensorflow, so excuse my stupid questions. I have been reading different tutorials as 'https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials' and 'https://github.com/u04617/deeplearning/blob/master/mnist_experiments.ipynb' 
unfortunately I have been confused by some difference in their writing. More specifically I have a question regarding opening a session:

1) what is the difference between

```
session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
```

and

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
optimizer.run({x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys, keep_prob: 0.5})
```

Indeed, I understand the basic idea behind each of these lines (open a session to execute the graph, initialize the variable for 
the graph and finally execute the graph given in a dictionary the needed input), but I don't understand the difference from the two above code, especially the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Both are working.

- In Jupyter Notebook files: use `InteractiveSession`

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50229091/7443104) to understand the difference between an `InactiveSession` and a `Session`.
But do not even try `eval()`. Please do yourself a favor and use the only correct and clean way:

```py
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

tf.get_default_graph().finalize()
with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(init_op)
  session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
```

The way of [`operation.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation#run), [`tensor.eval()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#eval) is spread somewhere in the internet. But there are tons of caveats:

Here are two of them:

[Tensorflow subtract strange result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962706/tensorflow-subtract-strange-result/48962971#48962971)

[Official ZeroOut gradient example error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'eval'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177766/official-zeroout-gradient-example-error-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-at/50177935#50177935)

I hope at some point they will deprecate `eval() at some point.

Comment: Thank you very much Patwie for your helpful answer! DO you have mroe details why I should use InteractiveSession()? Also, the correct way you suggest doe snot have this InteractiveSession(), so it does not meant to be the most correct way in jupyternotebook?